# how can i turn of kinematics using any kind of collision

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, kinematics

i have this wall and would like to turn off the kinematics thats holding up each brick using any type of collision any ideas?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj3Lp.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
public GameObject cube;


private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("KineOff"))
    {     
     Rigidbody cubeRigidbody = cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
     cubeRigidbody.isKinematic = false;
    }
}
```